# How to modify a decimal number inside a string C#?

Tags: c#, string

Let's consider we have the following strings.

```
string s1 = "$12.99"
string s2 = "11.49$"
string s3 = "€12.99"
string s4 = "11.49€"
```

Then as an example, we divide the first number by 3, second by 4, third by 5, fourth by 6.
So the output should be:

```
s1 == "$4.33"
s2 == "2.87$"
s3 == "€2.60"
s4 == "1.92€"
```

Considering we keep the same decimal places.

Edit: The strings are output of a method that I cannot modify.
I am looking to leave the symbol the same place it was before modifying the decimal number.

Comment: Use regex to extract the number part out and then do the math. Or you can use `String.Replace` method to replace the characters you don't want with `''` and then do the math. I suggest the former approach though the latter can work too but it's brittle.

Comment: Maybe explain where these strings are coming from. If you actually have to work with strings (a text file provided by someone else? Web scraping?), whether you have specific constraints in relation to the currency symbols or Cultures that may generate or use these values. Or if you do actually need to place the currency symbol as it was before you parsed to decimal, etc.

Comment: Pity that `Decimal.TryParseExact` doesn't exist, or you could just try each format, do your math, then reuse the format.

Comment: Invoking `Decimal.Parse`, which can deal with currency symbols (`NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol`) plus the appropriate CultureInfo will do. The requirement of having the same count of decimal places yields inexact / wrong results btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Regex` is your friend. You can use it to find and replace the decimal value within a string.

Try this:

```
private Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+((\.(?'dps'\d+))|)");
bool TryDividing(string input, decimal divisor, out string output)
{
    var match = regex.Match(input);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        var value = decimal.Parse(match.Value);
        var dps = match.Groups["dps"].Success ? match.Groups["dps"].Value.Length : 0;
        output = regex.Replace(input, (value / divisor).ToString($"F{dps}"));
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        output = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now you can write your code like this:

```
string s1 = "$12.99";
string s2 = "11.497$";
string s3 = "€12.9955";
string s4 = "11€";

foreach (var x in new[] { s1, s2, s3, s4 }.Select((s, n) => new { s, n = n + 3 }))
{
    if (TryDividing(x.s, x.n, out string o))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{x.s} divided by {x.n} becomes {o}");
    }
}
```

The output I get is:

```
$12.99 divided by 3 becomes $4.33
11.497$ divided by 4 becomes 2.874$
€12.9955 divided by 5 becomes €2.5991
11€ divided by 6 becomes 2€
```

NB: Formatting the last division to zero decimal places is introducing a significant error.

Comment: Assuming you always work with just two decimal places.

Comment: @dropoutcoder - Yes, the OP did say "Considering we keep the same decimal places" so I made that assumption. If that were not the case, or if a different decimal place symbol, or if there were thousand separators, etc, then the `Regex` could be extended to support all of those scenarios. The nice thing is that it's all encapsulated within `TryDividing` and thus it's a change in one place only.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thank you for the answer, but what if the input has 1 or 3 decimal places?
By "Considering we keep the same decimal places". I meant that the same number of decimal places would stay the same as the input.

Comment: @itsnottme - Your question only had 2 decimal places. Please ensure your questions are broad enough and clear enough to cover the actual cases you need. It's not hard to change the code to make it work. Do you need to see that?

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, sorry. would be great if the code can take any number of decimal places as inputs.

Comment: Let's hope there isn't something like `"$1,212.99"` in there :)

Comment: @Jimi - Yes, I mentioned that above. It's up to the OP to put forward the right sample input.

Comment: @Enigmativity The comment wasn't exactly directed to you. I also asked to provide the required details. This really looks like a superficial analysis of the input. What if it could also be (why not) `1 345,45 ₽`? @itsnottme Do you know how to modify the Regex, if that's the case?

Comment: @Jimi No, I don't have any experience with the Regex format.
It's unlikely for there to be any space between the numbers, but the input might have a non-decimal number like you said.

Comment: @Jimi - I agree. If the OP doesn't have control of the input then it's possible that there are many more variants than provided. And they could even change over time! It'd be great to know what the currently known formats could be.

Comment: @itsnottme - The number `1 345,45` is a perfectly fine decimal number. It's `1345.45`. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator) has this to say, "Space, the internationally recommended thousands separator".

Comment: @Enigmativity That's good to know, thanks.
The inputs should always follow a correct visual price number with a currency symbol.
Numbers should be less than a thousand.
I believe the only variant left is a non-decimal number.

Comment: @itsnottme - What does "correct visual price number" mean?

Comment: @Enigmativity Prices you would see in stores, such as google store and app store.

Comment: @itsnottme - Which is based on your, or the website's, regional settings. That's a correct price for you, but not necessarily everyone else.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to have an array of currencies signs e.g.
   `currencySigns={"$",euro”,…}`.
2. In each string find any sign (you may log an error if more than 1 sign found).
3. Remove it and remember position( before or after).
4. Do calculation( log error if unable to parse the string as numeric value).
5. Then add the sign to the same position as it was in original string (before or after)

Comment: What if I am unable to know all the signs that could be in the strings?

Comment: @itsnottme you can create a list of currency symbols by iterating over all the available cultures in Windows

Comment: @itsnottme, you can create array of all possible signs from site like https://www.xe.com/symbols.php. But if you trust the generator that any non (numeric or dot) character is considered as currency sign, then regex approach suggested by CodingYoshi   is safe enough.